Understanding refinement theorems of Lagrange's four-square theorem
I am reading Z.-W. Sun, "Refining Lagrange's four-square theorem" (2017), as I am trying to apply some of the theorems therein to reduce the search space in an algorithmic solution of mine to finding the four squares for given non-negative integer: and, AFAICT, I am failing to understand the very theorem statements in the paper.
Consider the following two theorems in particular:

Theorem 1.2. (iii)
Let $d \in \{1,2\}$ and $m \in \{2,3\}$.  Then, any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ with $x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+2y = dt^m$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Theorem 1.3. (i)
Let $m \in \{2,3\}$ and $(c,d) \in S(m)$ where $S(3) = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,4)\}$ and $S(2) = S(3) \cup \{(2,3),(2,6)\}$.  Then, any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ with $x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+y+cz = dt^m$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.


Firstly, I am reading those "let", e.g. "let $d$", to be universal quantifications, i.e. to be equivalent to "for any", e.g. "for any $d$".  Whence I specialize the two theorems to the simpler:

Theorem 1.2. (iii)' with $d = 1$, $m = 2$
Any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ with $x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+2y = t^2$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Theorem 1.3. (i)' with $m = 2$, $c = 1$, $d = 1$
Any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ with $x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+y+z = t^2$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.


Also, I am reading e.g. "exists $t$ s.t $x+2y = t^2$" as "$x+2y$ is a square", whence I further simplify the theorems to:

Theorem 1.2. (iii)''
Any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ with $x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+2y$ is a square.

Theorem 1.3. (i)''
Any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ with $x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x+y+z$ is a square.


Then, my idea in order to reduce the search space is to use Th.1.2.(iii)'' to put a constraint on $y$ given a candidate $x$, and Th.1.3.(i)'' to put a constraint on $z$ given candidate $x$ and $y$.
And there I am stuck, since those two constraints combined cannot be satisfied already in case $n = 3$.  (This, IIANM, easily follows by case analysis, given that the only decomposition of $3$ up to ordering is $[1,1,1,0]$.  For brevity, I won't try and write down the proof.)
So, as said, I am sure I am simply misreading the theorem statements and/or misunderstanding how to apply the theorems.  Could anyone please help/shed some light?

for speed   a greedy algorithm will be good: divide $n$   by 4 until it is not divisible by 8.   Next, let $W$   be the maximum with $W^2  \leq n$ Loop $w = W, W-1, W-2,..$   until $n - w^2 $ is not of the form $4^k (8 u -1) $  Then  $n_3 = n - w^2 $  is a sum of three squares;  Again, start with the largest possible $z^2 \leq n_3.$  Let $n_2 = n_3 - z^2.$  To find out whether $n_2$  is the sum of two squares, it really is necessary to obtain a partial factoring:  it   will be the sum of two squares if, in factoring, the exponent for any prime factor $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$   is even.

Thanks @WillJagy, I am/was indeed trying the greedy approach, but I am asked to handle input up to 1024 bits long (it's a Codewars kata) and, at this point, I don't think I am ever going to get a greedy algorithm that can handle that much, not even with the tighter bounds you have suggested: though I am going to try that anyway, even just for completeness of my exploration. -- And if, as I fear/expect, not even that is fast enough, I'll have to try and manage to parse Pollack-Trevino...

@WillJagy I have implemented your suggestions and I do get a significant speed-up, x5 to x10, maybe more, still apparently not enough to get past the 128 bit barrier... sounds right? -- That said, there might be a problem with your rule for sums of two squares, e.g. $2948918 = 27^230091$ fits the rule AIUI, yet it won't work: I get to it when solving $n = 784591244366183643317391$, with expected greedy solution $[885771553147, 1317187, 3917, 882]$)... any clue? (We could continue in a chat if you deem it appropriate and are interested. I suppose I am already abusing the comment space here.)

Julio, $30091  \equiv 3 \pmod 4$   I don't believe I know any paper by Pollack and Trevino.

But you said "for any prime factor so and so"... did you mean for all?

Yes, all prime factors $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$  must have even exponents for the number to be the sum of two squares.

I do have very hard times reading informal mathematics, especially in English... :)  Thanks very much for your help!

Your simplifications are correct, I believe. However,
first, the two conditions "$x+2y$ is a square" and "$x+y+z$ is a square" don't have to hold true for the same tuple $(x,y,z,w)$, and
second, $x,y,z,w$ are integers, not necessarily nonnegative, so we can take $(1,0,-1,1)$ for $n=3$, satisfying both conditions.

Thank you!  Your second remark I think fully answers my question: indeed, I had failed to consider negative integers altogether.  --  I am not sure about your first remark: the two constraints (on $y$ in terms of $x$, and on $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$) are indeed independent, but their conjunction (in fact, application in sequence) I think is also true: after all, $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary in the constraint for $z$, so why not...

Well, we can pull $x,y$ only from a restricted pool of values, so it doesn't seem to me that they can be chosen arbitrarily. However, I found no counterexample for $n$ below $1000$.

I think you are right on that, too: the order of components doesn't matter in a Lagrange decomposition, so I am eventually not even sure my application of the first theorem alone is justified, especially considering that I am finding components from left to right in non-increasing order of magnitude, while there is no constraint in those theorems that $x \ge y$, etc.  Never mind, eventually I don't think I am going to get any usable speed-ups from these "refinements" (and the two I have mentioned are the easiest to compute): just thanks again for helping me reading the theorems.
